# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (new install) not connecting to wireless router

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP laptop along with Windows 10. 
I use wi-fi router daily with windows to connect to internet. But when I am switching to UBUNTU, my laptop is not connecting to my router. If I use a LAN wire, it works fine. 
I tried many solutions as said on ubuntu forums, such as:

- In Settings->Software and Updates, I searched for drivers and clicked
  to use Broadcom 802.11 driver and restarted. Not worked.
- I restarted NetworkManager service, still did not work.

And in Menu bar, network manager is also not visible.

I searched through other solutions on askubuntu.com also, but nothing worked for me.

Please help me on this.

Comment: mention your laptop model and wifi chip details. that is too little info to help you.

Comment: My laptop model : 
HP 15-af114AU Notebook  <br/>Model #: P3C92PA  <br/>                                             _italic_ Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi M.2 Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     192.168.1.1
                                 IP address(es)
                           _italic_

Comment: Is secure boot enabled?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes secure boot is enabled.

Comment: It may be time for a bug report as the bcmwl-kernel-source module doesn't seem to be able to be used with secure boot enabled.  Try `sudo modprobe -v wl` and see if it returns errors `Required key not available` and `Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I ran the command `sudo modprobe -v wl` and got the following input  modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic.  and if it is a bug, where should I report it?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` reboot and see if wifi works or the results from `sudo modprobe -v wl` are different.  [Pilot6's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/300665) may help as there is a chance he is correct about the issue

Comment: @Jeremy31 I tried to install bcmwl-kernel-source, but it was already installed, however after tring @Pilot6 answer, the error message of `sudo modprobe -v wl` changed  and it showed **Required key not available**.  But it did not solve problem and finally I disabled secure boot. Is it safe to disable secure boot?

Comment: I don't use it on the one laptop I own that has the option